# Select pseudo-elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element

How would you convert this block of css into jquery?

```
.nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
    content:""; 
    position: absolute; 
    height:0; 
    width: 0; 
    border: 5px solid transparent; 
    top: 50% ;
    right:5px;  
}
```

I've tried a couple different ways but nothing I tried worked properly. Where this css selects only before the  the jquery selects the whole anchor.

```
$(".nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2)").before().css(...); // did not work

$(".nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2)").before(function(){
    $(this).css(...);
}); // did not work
```

I tried a lot of other stuff as well, let me know what you guys think, Thanks!

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Class Assignments</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Java</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="java1.php">Java 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="java2.php">Java 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="java3.php">Java 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="java4.php">Java 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javaScript1.php">JavaScript 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javaScript2.php">JavaScript 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javaScript3.php">JavaScript 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javaScript4.php">JavaScript 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Projects</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="project.php">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="project.php">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="project.php">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="project.php">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what it looks like with the css...

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the HTML code of your navigation?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `.nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before`? I made a fiddle and the CSS doesn't seem to affect any part of the code at all... http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/287y3s4s/

Comment: @Niffler it doesn't matter; you cannot manipulate pseudo-elements from JS.

Comment: @Mathletics I figured that since the CSS that's been given doesn't affect anything anyway, maybe the OP actually meant something other than ":before"... If not, then that's too bad of course...

Comment: The code in CSS works perfectly fine, the reason it didn't show is because I have another css affecting the color of it. So it's there you just can't see it..

Comment: @Foemilod Sorry, my mistake...

Comment: @Niffler I added an image as what the nav looks looks like with the css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that would work exactly the same as with `:before`, but what if you used jQuery to insert a `<span>`-tag instead, and then adjust the CSS of the `<span>`? I.e.

```
$(".nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2)").prepend('<span class="before-hack" />');
$('.before-hack').css(...);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/287y3s4s/9/

Comment: That worked, I wasn't aiming for the exact same way that css does it, I just wanted to accomplish the same goal. I didn't really make that specific but yeah. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't modify :before, :after pseudoselectors.

Solution for your problem is add css rules directly to css file.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

Comment: Not even with JQuery?

Comment: @Foemilod LOL jQuery __is__ JavaScript.

Comment: I know, but I was hoping it offered more features, where Javascript left something out, JQuery could have added it...

Comment: @Foemilod jQuery cannot do anything that JS cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

First store the css into an object:

```
     var css =
            {
           "content":"",
           "position":"absolute",
           "height":"0",
           "width":"0", 
           "border":"5px solid transparent",
           "top":"50%",
           "right":"5px"
            };
```

Then call the css function before any other functions:

```
        $(".nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2)").css(css).before(function(){


        });
```

I believe you will need to call the css function before the other functions.

Comment: This ended up smooshing the <a> elements together and messed up the nav, well it reduced their width to 0. I did try adding it before any other css as well. Which happened with my previous attempts..